# Adding custom shapes to JTextpane and saved to new Word document

Tags: java, ms-word, drawing, apache-poi, document

If I load a Word document into a `JTextPane`, is there a way I could drop a custom shape in it, then save it as a new Word document?

The results I'm looking for are just like dropping a shape anywhere onto the document using Insert-> Shapes in MS Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docx4all is a Swing-based docx editor.

Like DocxEditorKit, it is built on top of docx4j.

You'd need to extend it to support the functionality you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend the DocxEditorKit http://java-sl.com/docx_editor_kit.html adding your feature there